# Difference between two timestamps with different weekdays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime, weekday

I've the following dates:

```
Tue 19:00-20:00
Wed 04:25-15:14
```

How can i get the difference between `Tue 20:00` and `Wed 04:25`?

I've tried to transform it in `datetime` objects but since i don't have the day of the month or a year both objects will get the same date:

```
d1 = datetime.strptime("Tue 20:00", "%a %H:%M")
d2 = datetime.strptime("Wed 04:25", "%a %H:%M")
```

- d1 is: `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 20, 0)`
- d2 is: `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 4, 25)`

The difference in minutes should be `505` but in this case will be `-935.0` because they have the same date, and so they differ by almost 16 hours and not about 8 and a half:

```
diff = (d2 - d1).total_seconds() / 60  # -935.0
```

Comment: Are they always an earlier and a later date but at most 6 days apart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`datetime.strptime()` can't do anything else, because the day of the week is *not enough* to form a date. You'd need a week number and a year for a week-day to make any sense. If you need to get the *relative difference* between two dates that are assumed to be in the *same week*, then *any* week number and year would do, e.g.:

```
arbitrary_iso_week = "2020-25 "

d1 = datetime.strptime(arbitrary_iso_week + "Tue 20:00", "%G-%V %a %H:%M")
d2 = datetime.strptime(arbitrary_iso_week + "Wed 04:25", "%G-%V %a %H:%M")
```

This makes use of the [`%G` and `%V` formatters for ISO 8601 week numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

This produces datetime objects with a more meaningful date releationship:

```
>>> arbitrary_iso_week = "2020-25 "
>>> d1 = datetime.strptime(arbitrary_iso_week + "Tue 20:00", "%G-%V %a %H:%M")
>>> d2 = datetime.strptime(arbitrary_iso_week + "Wed 04:25", "%G-%V %a %H:%M")
>>> d1
datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 16, 20, 0)
>>> d2
datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 17, 4, 25)
>>> (d2 - d1).total_seconds() / 60
505.0
```

The actual dates don't matter here, just their difference in days. `d1` is now earlier, not later, than `d2`.

You may have to take into account that week days are circular, in that you could have an earlier date on, say, Friday, and a later date on Monday. If you can assume that the first value *must* be earlier than the second, then the solution is simple. Just subtract 7 days from `d1` if it is later than `d2`:

```
# if the first date must come before the second, then it must be one week earlier.
if d1 > d2:
    d1 -= timedelta(days=7)
```